# MySQL vs MariaDB - ddl - setting default for time field

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I've got table products, and want to add column with type time.
I've got statement as follows:

`ALTER TABLE products ADD openTime1 TIME DEFAULT TIME(now());`

it works on MariaDB, but it doesnt work on Mysql.
On mysql it produces Error -

```
[42000][1064] You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(now())' at line 1
```

Can someone tell me why? whats wrong here? I thought that this should be the same.

Comment: Well, it simply isn't true that mariadb and mysql are completely interchangeable. There are many differences. In MySQL 8.0 it is possible though, what you're trying to do.

Comment: In most (but not all) schemas, it is better to use a single `DATETIME` column, not two separate columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MySQL the expression used in DEFAULT field attribute **must be wrapped into the parenthesis**:

```
ALTER TABLE products ADD openTime1 TIME DEFAULT (TIME(now()));
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0bd6d9853192ab1fd9051161c85738b4)*